# How to set the cpumask of an unbound workqueue from within the kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I've noticed it's possible to set the cpumask of all unbound workqueues using  `workqueue_set_unbound_cpumask()`, however I don't see anything that will target a specific workqueue. The real thorn in my side is that `struct workqueue_struct` is defined within the source file, so I can't access any of its memebers.

One solution I have is to allocate a new `struct workqueue_attrs` and call `apply_workqueue_attrs()`. This would be fine if not for the fact that I can't access the aforementioned workqueue's `unbound_attrs` member. There seem to be some functions for copying but they are all internal. So now I'm left to reselect values for `nice` and `no_numa`, which is irritating since I have to pay attention to whether the workqueues are ordered and if they were allocated with `WQ_HIGHPRI`.

I know it's possible to do this is userspace with sysfs, but I don't want the user to have to track every workqueue that gets created and pin them all manually, nor have to pin every unbound workqueue.

Hopefully I'm missing something and there is an easier way. Code below for reference.

```
struct workqueue_struct* wq = alloc_workqueue(name, WQ_UNBOUND | WQ_HIGHPRI);
struct workqueue_attrs* attrs = alloc_workqueue_attrs(GFP_KERNEL);

/* Yuck, setting WQ_HIGHPRI is just declaring intent */
attrs->nice = MIN_NICE; 
attrs->no_numa = 0;
cpumask_parse(..., attrs->cpumask);

apply_workqueue_attrs(wq, attrs);
```